# Countdown Pyramid error

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to get a pyramid that counts:

```
      1
     121
    12321
   1234321
  123454321
```

this is my code

```
 for (int i=5; i>=1; i--){
        for (int j=5; j>= (i-1); j--){
            System.out.print("");
    }
        for (int j=i; j<=5; j++){
            System.out.print(j);
        }
    System.out.println();
```

but this keeps giving my the output

```
     1
    222
   33333
  4444444
 555555555
```

How can i get the right side of my pyramid to count down

Comment: I removed the JavaScript tag and added Java, since the syntax is clearly Java syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working implementation.  Your approach to the problem seems good to me, but the third inner loop had a problem.  Instead of counting from 1 upwards, it was also counting down.  Instead just use the approach of a single outer loop, to cover each row of the pyramid, along with three inner loops.  The first loop can print spaces, and the next two will count, then up, respectively.

```
int row = 1;
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    for (int o=1; o<=5-i; o++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int k=1; k<=i; k++) {
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    for (int k = i-1; k >= 1; k--){                    
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    System.out.println();  
    row++;
}
```

**Output:**

```
    1
   121
  12321
 1234321
123454321
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

This is a method to print pyramid:

```
public void print(int height) {
    for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
        for (int j=height; j>=1; j--) {
            if (j <= i+1) {
                System.out.print(j);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }

        for (int j=2; j<=height; j++) {
            if (j <= i+1) {
                System.out.print(j);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```